# Static and dynamic class in the same element. Polymer

Tags: polymer

How to define in the same DOM element a dynamic class and another static?

I tried this:

```
class$="{{clase}} my-static-class" 
class$="[{{clase}}, 'my-static-class']" 
class$="{{clase}}" class="my-static-class"
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: could you do: `class$="{{getClasses}}"` and then define a `function` called `getClasses` that returns a `String` with the class names to apply?

Comment: Hi Benhjt!  Thanks for the response.  This sure works, but i want to know the right syntaxis for add static classes if it's possible

Comment: Also, have a look at these [Utility functions](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html). There is a function there for toggling classes on elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation is not yet supported on Polymer 1.0. However, you can use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) for this.

```
Polymer({
  ...
  computeClass: function(someClass) {
    return someClass + ' my-static-class';
  }
});
```

And use accordingly:

```
<div class$="{{computeClass(clase)}}"></div>
```